# What does "!?" mean on the island map?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

When I consult the island map, some regions show a `[⁉]` when selected. I'm assuming this means something is hidden in that area. What hidden items does `[⁉]` denote? Will it go away when I find the hidden item?

Comment: Hmm... I have been around looking for information on this, but there appears to be none. Perhaps it is some sort of quest indicator or something?

Comment: When you're viewing the map, hit the A button to examine these locations (or any location specially marked) for further details. This should tell you exactly what point of interest is in that location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Places with a ⁉ symbol on the map are just places of interest. Locations include people's houses, phone booths and the Wind Fish Egg.

Comment: I thought this as well, but its interesting to note that some other places of interest are marked more explicitly, eg shop icons.

Comment: @indeed these seem to be generic points of interest that aren't shops, dungeons, or the owl's advice.